# Exclude word from grep when using context flags?

Tags: grep

Is there some way to remove unwanted lines from a `grep` result, that doesn't conflict with showing context (`-A`, `-B`), colorizing matches (`--color`) or showing of file names and line numbers (`-nH`)?

Consider e.g. grepping a complicated multi-file compilation log, to see files that where compiled against `alpha.o` but not against `beta.o`. If I only want the lines without any of the other features, I could do something like

```
find -name "make.log" -exec grep 'alpha.o' {} \; | grep -v 'beta.o'
```

Is there any chance to apply a similar filter to

```
find -name "make.log" -exec grep --color -A 3 -B 3 -nH 'alpha.o' {} \;
```

### Minimal working example.

This is a toy example, since the real-world example is a corporate product. I couldn't come up with a good way of providing a succiently large realistic example here.

```
# Reproducible random file.
# -- example.bash --

mkdir -p /tmp/foo
cd /tmp/foo
RANDOM=0 # Seed it.
for ((i=0;i<10000;i++)); do
    printf ' %04x%04x' $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM
    if (($RANDOM % 100 > 1)); then 
        printf ' 0a00%04x' $RANDOM
    else
        printf ' %04x%04x' $RANDOM $RANDOM
    fi
    printf ' %04x%04x' $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM
    printf '\n'
done | split -l 1000 - data.
```

Then let's say I want all lines with a number starting with `0a`.

```
>>> grep '\b0a' /tmp/foo/data.* | head
/tmp/foo/data.aa: 6b883baf 6aae6938 000000 0a006f96 0f0c1675 71d417cd
/tmp/foo/data.aa: 2ba4446a 21070bd0 000001 0a007681 465322a8 54e20231
/tmp/foo/data.aa: 7bc17b37 2d493c77 000002 0a006c68 30a96b30 735456a8
/tmp/foo/data.aa: 4f707722 7d5d1b6f 000003 0a002602 7801346c 7285394a
/tmp/foo/data.aa: 49a60fcf 38e90f7d 000004 0a007c69 14e11a16 7549690e
... (and 9000 more lines) ...
```

I notice that there is a recurring pattern of a column starting with '0a00'. Let's see if there are any more interesting patterns.

```
>>> grep -n '\b0a' /tmp/foo/data.* | grep -v '\b0a00'
/tmp/foo/data.aa:607: 21c1631c 09fd779d 37435823 12873910 0aa64882
/tmp/foo/data.aa:759: 1d213f2c 0ac76099 5c0719c5 26c1265c 30db2bc3
/tmp/foo/data.ab:677: 09b2512f 0ac0772e 5e9156f6 6f396505 5e027e02
/tmp/foo/data.ad:102: 1a191fad 582104da 4cdd7c5c 3d624820 0aa863fa
/tmp/foo/data.af:556: 559b7651 0a6c0a34 34612ac1 29567c5c 2f62187f
...
```

For easier viewing it might be nice to add colorization. But that breaks the filter rule, due to the ansi escape sequences!

[image]

Things get weird from here. As a workaround, we might re-add highlighting after the fact, but it doesn't colorize the file/linenumber columns.

[image]

Likewise, adding context with `-A`, `-B` will require effort. E.g. `grep -n -A 3 '\b0a' /tmp/foo/data.* | grep -v '\b0a00'` will give unsatisfactory results, as it isn't aware of the context lines.

Likewise the filename and line number part may cause issues. For instance we may want to exclude lines where the search strings is at the start of the line (`grep -v '^PATTERN'`) which can't be easily done, when the output contains file names.

Piping a grep result to `grep -v` thus quickly leads to bad maintainability ad overly complicated constructs.

Comment: Sounds like a good question, upvoted. But still, you should add some examples we can work on

Comment: Add some test data, I'm too lazy to create my own. And, try to adhere to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) criteria when asking questions

Comment: @Thor Added some example. I didn't originally, because anything that I can upload is a toy example far removed from real applications. All cases where I ran into it are either problematic in terms of privacy (e.g. filtering data from Keepass) or fall under business secret regulations, or are simply too large for posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the easiest way may be to reverse the logic, and applying the exclusion pattern *first*.

### Example

E.g. for the example in the question, instead of `grep -n '\b0a' /tmp/foo/data.* | grep -v '\b0a00'` one can do

```
>>> grep --color=always -nH -v '\b0a00' /tmp/foo/data.* | grep --color '\b0a'
#                |
#                 ` Without 'always' color wouldn't be applied 
#                   when piping the result.
```

and receive fully colored output:

[image]

The same method works with `-A`, `-B`.

[image]

### Pro

- Doesn't require tools that may not be installed on a given system.

### Contra

- The distinction between match lines (`FILENAME:000: ...`) and context lines (`FILENAME-000- ...`) is lost.
- The number/name prefix makes grepping for "at the beginnining of the line" patterns awkward still. Instead of `^foo` one has to grep for `^.*?:.*?: foo`. Even that doesn't work well with the 'color' solution, which can be solved by using postprocessing coloration as described in [Thor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59159423/2075630). But then we are back to installing additional tools.

Answer (score 1):

I see two approaches to this:

1. Keep the escape sequences and include them in your patterns
2. Post-highlight the text

#### Including escape sequences in your patterns

Below is an example that works here. You may need to tweak which escape sequences you are matching:

```
# Define the coloring reset sequence
rst=$'\x1b\\\[m\x1b\\\[K'
grep --color=always -n '\b0a' /tmp/foo/data.* | grep -vE "0a${rst}00"
```

Output:

```
/tmp/foo/data.aa:39: 4d633499 398a4f7a 0a935cbd 2c4f2c3a 154f7a91
/tmp/foo/data.ab:178: 0a1300b0 2ad5117e 572b548e 68040659 5dee37bf
/tmp/foo/data.ab:636: 02e05497 0cfe1378 0ab90ea2 36aa7fb2 0ee64bbb
/tmp/foo/data.ac:369: 3e1173bd 0a2b4bb0 075d7b29 53336401 30407990
/tmp/foo/data.ac:578: 00f22d00 0a826912 79b16c04 27ab7fbb 02085f85
/tmp/foo/data.ac:690: 44847461 12384d93 6f35227c 2a1f1421 0a68356f
/tmp/foo/data.ad:27: 07443f46 3a59377e 2fb731a6 31996a1e 0aab0e69
/tmp/foo/data.aj:158: 3c90509b 0a5e5803 3e8d50cd 7e89059d 292b723f
```

[image: With color]

#### Highlighting after the fact

Here is an example of how to do it with [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php):

Save this file to langDefs directory (there is room for improvement):

*grep.lang*

```
Description="Grep"

Digits=[[ [:-]\d+[:-] ]]

Keywords={
  { Id=1,
    Regex=[[^[^:-]+]],
  },
  { Id=2,
    Regex=[[ ^--$ ]],
  },
}
```

You can now do something like this:

```
grep -n -A3 '\b0a' /tmp/foo/data.* | grep -vE '0a00' | highlight -S grep -O ansi
```

[image: with colors]